# how to add a click event to extjs autoel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If i add a button like this

```
xtype: 'component',
autoEl: {
  html: '<input type="submit" class="custom_loginbtn" value="Submit"  id="login"/>'
}
```

any idea how to add a click event to this ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding listener

```
listeners: {
              render: function(component){
                   component.getEl().on('click', function(e){
                   console.log(component);
                   alert('test');
                     });    
               }
            }
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TFCWQ/)

Comment: be careful with this. your render listener will add an onClick event to the underlying element however render event could potentially fire again.

Answer (score 2):

```
xtype   : 'component',
itemId  : 'submitbtn',
autoEl  : {
  html  : '<input type="submit" class="custom_loginbtn" value="Login" id="login"/>'
},
listeners   : {
  el : {
    delegate : 'input',
    click    : function()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best approach, notice the use of a managed listener with `.mon()` in place of `.on()` which is better to use when you're listening to DOM elements from components that could be destroyed

```
xtype: 'component'
,html: '<input type="submit" class="custom_loginbtn" value="Submit"  id="login"/>'
,listeners: {
    afterrender: function(inputCmp) {
        inputCmp.mon(inputCmp.el, 'click', function(){alert('click!')}, this, {delegate:'input'});
    }
    ,single: true
}
```

Also, your use of autoEl is analogous to just setting the html property of the component, other options in autoEl let you manipulate type and attributes of the outer tag that is automatically created to encompass the component

If you did this instead you could turn turn the component itself into an `<input>` and avoid the wrapping `<div>`:

```
xtype: 'component'
,autoEl: {
    tag: 'input'
    ,cls: 'custom_loginbtn'
    ,type: 'submit'
    ,value: 'Submit'
}
,listeners: {
    afterrender: function(inputCmp) {
        // no delegate needed, since inputCmp.el is the <input>
        inputCmp.mon(inputCmp.el, 'click', function(){alert('click!')}, this);
    }
    ,single: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a standard submit button, why not use an xtype button? - it has a handler you can specify for your click event.

Comment: because i need to use a css styled button instead of extjs button

Comment: have you looked into styling extjs buttons? or using background image ?

Comment: yup style i try to apply is not working with extjs default button though

Comment: apply css like    .custom_submitbtn { background: #3197CA url(img/bg_login_btn.png) repeat-x top; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border: none; font-size: 25px; font-weight: 700; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9cced6; color: #1C5571; width: 200px; padding: 11px 0; margin: 5px 0 0 0; display: block; cursor: pointer; border-top: 1px solid #BEDFEF; letter-spacing: -1px; }

Comment: Just do this: your button config => type: 'button', text: 'Login',
                        iconCls: 'login',
                        handler: function() {//dosomething}      .....  And in your css file: .login{background-image:url(../img/bg_loginbtn.png);}

Comment: yeah that just add the icon to button's left side. not the output i expect though. i have done what you suggested in few apps i build with extjs. just looking for do something new in this project. i will post some screens what im trying to do